# How to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE(vcpkg) without put it in CMakeLists.txt in VScode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I want to use vcpkg in my group project and we set CI/CD(github action) for it. For this reason, I can't set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE directly in CMakeLists.txt because its path is different for others. So how can I set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE in VScode?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it as command line parameter!

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/vcpkg.cmake
```

If you use the CMake extension for VSCode, you can add the parameter into the <kbd>CMake Configure Args</kbd> configuration entry.

Comment: run command
```cmake .. "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/xxx/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"```
I got following error:
```Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Drogon" with any
  of the following names:
```
but I have installed it
```sudo vcpkg install Drogon
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    drogon[core,ctl]:x64-linux -> 1.7.1
Package drogon:x64-linux is already installed
```

Comment: You have to recreate the build directory when specifying a toolchain file